# Keystrokes handled: Understanding IntPtr return value

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to understand a code which block some keys on the keyboard and allows only some exit paths, as compared to normal methods.

I have been able to get most of it, but there's this part in which we are actually handling the keystrokes in this function.
Here's the code:

```
public static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
      {
         if (nCode >= 0)
         {
            bool Alt = (WinForms.Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Alt) != 0;
            bool Control = (WinForms.Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) != 0;

            //Prevent ALT-TAB and CTRL-ESC by eating TAB and ESC. Also kill Windows Keys.
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            Keys key = (Keys)vkCode;

            if (Alt && key == Keys.F4)
            {
               Application.Current.Shutdown();
               return (IntPtr)1; //handled
            }
            if (key == Keys.LWin ||key == Keys.RWin) return (IntPtr)1; //handled
            if (Alt && key == Keys.Tab)  return (IntPtr)1; //handled
            if (Alt && key == Keys.Space) return (IntPtr)1; //handled
            if (Control && key == Keys.Escape)return (IntPtr)1;
            if (key == Keys.None) return (IntPtr)1; //handled
            if (key <= Keys.Back) return (IntPtr)1; //handled
            if (key == Keys.Menu ) return (IntPtr)1; //handled
            if (key == Keys.Pause) return (IntPtr)1; //handled
            if (key == Keys.Help) return (IntPtr)1; //handled
            if (key == Keys.Sleep) return (IntPtr)1; //handled
            if (key == Keys.Apps) return (IntPtr)1; //handled
            if (key >= Keys.KanaMode && key <= Keys.HanjaMode) return (IntPtr)1; //handled
            if (key >= Keys.IMEConvert && key <= Keys.IMEModeChange) return (IntPtr)1; //handled
            if (key >= Keys.BrowserBack && key <= Keys.BrowserHome) return (IntPtr)1; //handled
            if (key >= Keys.MediaNextTrack && key <= Keys.OemClear) return (IntPtr)1; //handled

            Debug.WriteLine(vkCode.ToString() + " " + key);


         }
         return InterceptKeys.CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
      }
```

What does assigning `boolean` value to Alt with the `&` symbol mean in this line `WinForms.Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Alt` ?

We have handled the keystrokes, but what the point about about returning an `IntPtr` of 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Keys.Alt` enumeration value is a bit mask that has the bit set that determines if the <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier key is pressed.

The `&` operator does a bitwise and when used on two `int` or `Enum` values, so doing that on the `WinForms.Control.ModifierKeys` singles out the bit for the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

The method returns an `IntPtr` value, so to return the value `1` that specifies that the key was handled, you have to cast it to `IntPtr`.

Comment: I earlier used in one of my applications with e.KeyChar == Keys.Alt in Keypress event. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @Cipher: That is a different use, as then you catch when the Alt key is pressed down, while the `ModifierKeys` property contains the modifier keys that are currently held down.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` symbol is used to do a bitwise `and` on the two arguments.  In this case `WinForms.Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Alt` is checking to see if the `Alt` key has been pressed.